using "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.19.6",
I am using Mui dataGrid ,I want function call on Columns toggle Changed can anyone help me their ?
<DataGrid
  
    rows={leads}
    columns={columnsToShow}
    components={{
      Toolbar: GridToolbar,
    }}
    componentsProps={{
      toolbar: {
        onColumnsChanged: handleColumnSelection,
        
        printOptions: { disableToolbarButton: true },
        showQuickFilter: true,
        quickFilterProps: { debounceMs: 250 },
      },
    }}

    getRowClassName={getRowClassName} // Set row class name based on deadline_expired
  />

accurate this
